# There is a problem in my code on line 5 stating "Missing '()' invoking a constructor" and i don't know how to debug that

Tags: javascript, json

```
var Discord = require('discord.io');
var logger = require('nugget#2115');
var auth = require('./auth.json');
logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(new logger.transports.Console, {
    colorize: true
});
logger.level = 'debug';
var bot = new Discord.Client({
   token: auth.token,
   autorun: true
});
bot.on('ready', function (evt) {
    logger.info('Connected');
    logger.info('Logged in as: ');
    logger.info(bot.username + ' - (' + bot.id + ')');
});
bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
    if (message.substring(0, 1) == '!') {
        var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
        var cmd = args[0];

        args = args.splice(1);
        switch(cmd) {
            case 'ping':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: 'Pong!'
                });
            break;
        }
     }
});
```

The rest of the code has no errors apart from Line 5:
"Missing '()' invoking a constructor"
I've tried adding '()' but they just won't work.

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess, your code says `new logger.transports.Console`. That's a constructor invocation with `new` but without the parantheses.

Change it to: `new logger.transports.Console()`